# .htaccess 301 redirect and some sort of suppress (cloaking)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iframe, redirect

Perhaps someone can help me if there is a solution for it.

I was using an iframe to redirect while suppressing the destination url - but this tactic is not ok.

So, I moved to .htaccess which I can do a 301 redirect or suppress the destination url, is there any way I can put the 2 together:

1. I used [P] which suppress the URL but it is not 301 redirect
   friendly
2. I used [R=301] which is redirect friendly but can not suppress the URL
3. Tried combining them together but it didn't work

Why do I want to suppress? Because I am pulling from a database with a very strange link. I don't want users to see this crazy link nor I want to have problems with hackers AGAIN....it drove me crazy last year until I cloaked.

Please help with a solution that would solve my problem and be Google friendly.

EDITING

.htaccess 301 redirect OK

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thesite\.com$
RewriteRule ^destination\.html$ "http\:\/\/www\.thesite\.com\/dbname\/subdbname\/result\.php" [R=301,L]
```

When trying it with "not-sure if it exist option" using request_uri

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thesite\.com$
RewriteRule ^destination\.html$ "http\:\/\/www\.thesite\.com\/dbname\/subdbname\/result\.php" [S=1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/db\/subdbname\/result\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "destination\.html" [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't redirect and internal redirect at the same time.  You need to provide more information. Sample URL the user is supposed to see, the strange link it's supposed to go to and current code you have tried.

Comment: I just edit the post by adding current code and the one I've tried.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to 301 redirect? Why do you need to redirect if you are trying to **hide** the URL? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Because Google was picking up (indexing) the 2 pages, the html and iframe with the php. I am open for suggestions, do you have any? Thank you

Comment: I'm still unclear of what you are trying to accomplish. Forget everything you were trying to do including the redirects. What is your main end goal? Is it to just hide a URL? What do you not want the external users to see?

Comment: Yes, to hide the URL, I want them to see www.thesite.com/destination.html - again thanks